# Trying to delete and create folders in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fs

It's very simple what I'm trying to achieve. I have an array of folders.

I want to loop through the folders

- Check if it exists : if it does delete it (if it contains files/folders or not)
- Create a new empty folder
- Copy a file into the new folder

The problem I'm getting is not fully understanding async function and Promises. So I suspect the "Copy the file into the new folder" is running before the deletion / creation is finished.

Here's my code (don't laugh)

```
async function checkFolder(folder) {
    if (fs.existsSync(folder)) {
        (async() => {
            const deleted = del.sync(folder, { force: true })
        })().then(async() => {
            return await makeDir.sync(folder)
        })
    } else {
        (async() => {
            return await makeDir.sync(folder)
        })
    }
}

const startBuild = async(folders) => {

    for (const a of folders) {
        await checkFolder(folders).then(() => {
            fs.copyFile(<some other folder>/template/file', <target folder>/file, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    // do something with the error
                }
           });
        })
    }
}

startBuild(folders)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use the "sync" versions only you don't have to mess around with promises at all. Plus, returning something from inside a `then()` callback function does *not* return anything in the encompassing function. Your `checkFolder` function returns an empty Promise that resolves immediately, but only thanks to the `async` in its declaration. With promise functions you do one of two things: either a) create a basic function that returns a promise, then `await` the function call elsewhere or b) create an `async function` that awaits something else, then returns a result.

Comment: Seems like you're using sync functions in the `checkFolder` function, are you sure you need to make it async?

Comment: Thanks guys. You put me on the right track. Simplified the code and it's working. If you post as an answer I'll up vote you. Thanks again.